# Selenium Python - cannot select options selection box

Tags: python, selenium, select

A website about stocks has a nice chart with several options for displaying the chart (see https://www.boerse.de/chart-tool/HeidelbergCement-Aktie/DE0006047004). I always need the chart for different stocks, but always with the same settings for the chart, so I would like to automate the selection of the settings for the chart. For example, I would always like to select the option "Barchart" (`<option value = "Balken"> Bar-Chart </option>`) in the select box for the chart type `<select id = "types"`). But I can't control the options in the chart. Possibly because it's a multilayered selection box.

In this respect, my (not working) code is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
url ="https://www.boerse.de/chart-tool/HeidelbergCement-Aktie/DE0006047004"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(10)
target = driver.find_element_by_class_name("box_full")
target.location_once_scrolled_into_view
driver.maximize_window()
select = Select(driver.find_element(By.ID,"types"))
select.select_by_value(“Balken”) # that doesn’t work
```

I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/peter/Desktop/Python2020/Selenium/Selenium02.py", line 52, in <module>
    select.select_by_value('Balken')
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-Charttyp <select id="types")  packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py", line 82, in select_by_value
    self._setSelected(opt)
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py", line 212, in _setSelected
    option.click()
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 693, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 418, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\peter\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
  (Session info: chrome=94.0.4606.81)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `"element not intractable"` error usually means the element is not visible or there is some other element on top of it, therefore selenium can't interact with it.

Solution is check if the `#types` element is actually visible on the screen when you try to interact with it.

You might be able to change the select value through pure javascript too, using `execute_script`, but that might have the downside of not triggering events that would supposedly be triggered.

Comment: I also thought that it was due to the fact that you can't see the selection menu. That's why I built a corresponding scroll into the script. But that doesn't help. I suspect it has something to do with the special construction of this menu on the website, which you can see here: https://www.boerse.de/chart-tool/HeidelbergCement-Aktie/DE0006047004)